Как дублировать сообщение в телеграм канал из Дискорда?
Есть задача: при отправке любого сообщения в определенный канал дискорда оно должно перенаправляться в телеграм канал. Насколько почитал, использование для этого телеграм-бота необязательно, но вот с пересылкой через API не работал. Проконсультируйте. Вот пример
   if ((message.content === "!тест") && (message.channel.id === '1010101010101010101')) {
        ...
   }

